# How to add resource folder to classpath in Java command line options

Tags: java, maven, command-line

I am trying to run Junit test cases from command line.

I fire my tests in windows system from a folder `D:\WorkSpace\Testspace\MyProject\target` like this :

```
java -cp "classes;junit;dependency\*"  org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.abc.TestA
```

This is a maven project. It throws the following error :

```
2019-07-09T17:59:41.330 ERROR [com.abc.IOUtil] - FileNotFoundException Occurredjava.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\WorkSpace\Testspace\MyProject\target\cde\FGH\SomeRandomFile.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)IOUtil
```

This `cde` folder containing the xmls is also inside the `target` folder from which I am firing my test commands.

Is there any way to include the resource files in java command line?

Answer (score 1):

In your source code, use the following construct:

```
package com.foo.package;

public class Example {
    public void loadResourceExample) {
         Example.class.getResource("/cde/FGH/SomeRandomFile.xml");
         Example.class.getResource("relative/example.xml");
    }
}
```

The first line will load resource "/cde/FGH/SomeRandomFile.xml" from any folder or jar mentioned in the classpath, so in your example command line, `D:\WorkSpace\Testspace\MyProject\target\classes\cde\FGH\SomeRandomFile.xml` would for example be scanned.

The second line takes the package name of your class into account, so, it would for example check at `D:\WorkSpace\Testspace\myProject\dependency\somedep.jar` for entry `/com/foo/package/relative/example.xml`.

Note that the * syntax in the -cp parameter will take every *JAR* inside the stated folder and include it in the classpath. That's all it does.

If you are not using the `getResource`, you're dependent on the 'current working directory' which can be anything, really, and the -cp parameter wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: So for reading the xml, I have to refactor the code and use `getResource` and there isn't any way to pass them as options from command line ?

Comment: If you want to pass the location of the XML file on the command line, you can do so of course. But then resource no longer factors into it; then you treat it as a plain jane file. Use java.nio.files.Path and Files API. Something like Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(paramPassedByUser)). paramPassedByUser has to be a plain old file path; something like `/Users/Tony/Documents/example.xml`