# Compile two source folders with javac

Tags: java, eclipse

Using eclipse, the program runs correctly if I add the folder I need, to the build path.

How would I compile and run the program with the command line?. I need to include another folder (resources folder with icons and images) but I didn't find a way to do it.

**EDIT:**

To compile it I did this:

```
 dir /s /B *.java > sources.txt
 javac -cp "lib/*" -encoding iso-8859-15 @sources.txt -d Salida
```

Then for running it:

```
 java -cp "./Salida;./lib/*" simulator.launcher.Main
```

Its a GUI program, the problem is that I need the resources folder too, without it the icon don't show.

**Folder structure:**

```
├───lib (External libraries)
├───resources
│   └───icons
├───Salida (Compiled code)
└───src (Code)
    ├───extra
    │   └───json
    └───simulator
        ├───control
        ├───factories
        ├───launcher
        ├───misc
        ├───model
        └───view
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018804/how-to-access-to-resources-in-external-resource-folder-in-java-9-modular-project

Comment: What do you mean by "on the command line". You don't need resources to compile code, so are you asking how to use the jar tool or something?

Comment: Provide your specific example. It's difficult to judge what you want to do based only on this text you have as a question.

Comment: Just for reference, the JDK tools have proper documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

Comment: What I want to do is running it with the resources folder too, eclipse use the folder and run the GUI correctly

Comment: ... so it is a simple matter of learning what the classpath is. V.C.s answer is as good as any then.

Comment: I'm pretty new to compiling it manually, but I think I specified the classpath correctly, I tried adding the folder with the icons to both classpath and sourcepath but the icons are still not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the classpath and sourcepath options as specified for the compiler, look at the `Javac -help` output on the command line.
specifically

```
    -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
    -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
```

These show you the syntax for the inclusions.

> -cp path or -classpath path
>
> Specify where to find user class files, and (optionally) annotation processors and source files. This class path overrides the user class path in the CLASSPATH environment variable. If neither CLASSPATH, -cp nor -classpath is specified, the user class path consists of the current directory. See Setting the Class Path for more details.
>
> If the -sourcepath option is not specified, the user class path is also searched for source files.

From:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

> In your source code, use the following construct:
>
> ```
> package com.foo.package;
>
>    public class Example {
>        public void loadResourceExample) {
>         Example.class.getResource("/cde/FGH/SomeRandomFile.xml");
>         Example.class.getResource("relative/example.xml");
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> The first line will load resource "/cde/FGH/SomeRandomFile.xml" from any folder or jar mentioned in the classpath, so in your example command line, D:\WorkSpace\Testspace\MyProject\target\classes\cde\FGH\SomeRandomFile.xml would for example be scanned.
>
> The second line takes the package name of your class into account, so, it would for example check at D:\WorkSpace\Testspace\myProject\dependency\somedep.jar for entry /com/foo/package/relative/example.xml.

From:

[How to add resource folder to classpath in Java command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952954/how-to-add-resource-folder-to-classpath-in-java-command-line-options)

examples of how to load the resources.

Comment: This is not the answer, but rather some counter-question and discussion.

Comment: I already checked it, the sourcepath just add me errors